# How to convert a time series into something useful?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a time series in the following format:

```
         Date        SKU Sales
1  2014-01-02 000823307B     5
2  2014-01-03 0008233043    52
3  2014-01-03 000823307B     4
4  2014-01-04 000823307B    10
5  2014-01-05 000823307B     1
6  2014-01-06 0008233043    10
7  2014-01-06 0008233053    43
8  2014-01-06 000823307B     7
9  2014-01-07 0008233043    30
10 2014-01-07 0008233053     5
```

I would like to find out if the sales of the different SKUs correlate. How can I do this in R? I struggle to find a starting point. I don't quite understand how to convert this into a ts object and if this would be the right approach.

---

After reading the comments I figured the question might be difficult to understand for some people. Luckily I got some very useful hints as well.
I will solve the problem by creating a pivot table and then trying to group the sales data by week. By doing this I should be able to draw a line diagram showing the different sales of the products, and also correlate the different sales pattern.

Comment: Questions seeking very non-specific help are often not answered or put on hold for lack of trying. Consider showing what you've tried so far. Have you checked any resources on-line that talk about coercing different objects into a time series?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a cluster analysis, or how to do a pivot chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your data such that each SKU  is a variable and each day/month (choose a time period that can give you meaningful values for correlation) is an observation.

You can then perform a PCA using princomp() or prcomp(). This would be a sufficient starting point.